# Arithmetic between two columns, lagged by one row in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Wasn't sure the best way to word this, but I'd like to multiple / divide two columns by each other, lagged by one row (in my dataset this means varx/vary - 1 row).

The end result should be an additional column, with one NA value (for the first year which isn't present)

I'm having trouble indexing it, but I think it would go something along these lines...

e.g.

```
df <- data_frame(year = c(2010:2020), var_x = c(20:30), var_y = c(2:12))


#not correct
diff <- df[,2, 2:ncol(df)-1] * df[,3, 1:ncol(df)]
```

```
dplyr would look something like...

df %>% 
  mutate(forecast = (var_x * ncol(var_y)-1))

incorrect result:
# A tibble: 11 x 4
    year var_x var_y forecast
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>
 1  2010    20     2       40
 2  2011    21     3       63
 3  2012    22     4       88
 4  2013    23     5      115
 5  2014    24     6      144
 6  2015    25     7      175
 7  2016    26     8      208
 8  2017    27     9      243
 9  2018    28    10      280
10  2019    29    11      319
11  2020    30    12      360


Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `forecast` must be length 11 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
```

Thanks, your guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a case of `mutate(forecast = var_x * lag(var_y))`

Comment: Thank you @arg0naut, I was unaware of `lag()`. Do you mind if I submit this as my own answer, or would you like to?

Comment: Go ahead, though this may be closed as a duplicate as I'm sure there's something similar

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find, it but likely. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From recommended comment above:

```
df %>% 
mutate(forecast = var_y * lag(var_x))

# A tibble: 11 x 4
    year var_x var_y forecast
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>
 1  2010    20     2       NA
 2  2011    21     3       60
 3  2012    22     4       84
 4  2013    23     5      110
 5  2014    24     6      138
 6  2015    25     7      168
 7  2016    26     8      200
 8  2017    27     9      234
 9  2018    28    10      270
10  2019    29    11      308
11  2020    30    12      348
```